# insert into binary tree in c

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, binary-tree

Below there are 3 segments of my code which function is create a binary tree for [word's hash code, occurencies] pairs. For some reason, when I add 2 same hash codes, it assumes that they are different.

```
typedef struct node { 
    // data[int, int]=[hash da palavra, ocorrencias da palavra]
    int* data[2]; 
    struct node* left; 
    struct node* right; 
    struct node* parent; 
} node;
```

```
node* searchedNode=NULL;
void searchNode(node* roott, int* data){
    if(roott != NULL){
        if(roott->data[0] == data[0]){
            searchedNode=roott;
        }else{
            if(data[0] <= roott->data[0]){
                searchNode(roott->left, data);
            }else{
                searchNode(roott->right, data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
node* insert(node* node, int* data){
    if (node->data != NULL) { 
        searchNode(node, data);
        if(searchedNode!=NULL){
            searchedNode->data[1]=searchedNode->data[1]+1;
            return searchedNode;
        }else{
            if (data[0] <= node->data[0]){  
                node->left  = insert(node->left, data); 
                node->left->parent=node;
            }else{
                node->right = insert(node->right, data); 
                node->right->parent=node;
            }
            return node; 
        } 
    }else{
        printf("RAIZ NOT FOUND\n");
        return(newNode(data, NULL)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering that the `data` member is an array of *pointers*, neither `searchedNode->data[1]+1` nor `data[0] <= node->data[0]` really works as you expect (I guess). Try making it an array of `int` *values* instead.

Comment: It does not work with "3 segments of my code", please make a [mre].